# solar panel 160w inverter wattage

Tags: solar-cell

I'd like to start with a couple DIY experiences into solar panels.

My question is regarding the inverter wattage.

I mean, if I pretend to make a cheap solar panel with a maximum possible wattage of 150w, connected to a 12v 20Ah battery. Should I buy a specific inverter for medium-small size projects?? Or could I buy, let's just say, a 1000w one? because gradually I'd like to increase the size of my projects in the future (and save some money)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider a bigger battery like 85Ah : at 150W the 20Ah one holds less than 2 hours charge (and you may exceed its max permissible charge rate)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to pay more for now to buy a 1000w inverter. It save you money in long term, and You can still use it for 150W solar panel for now..

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading a lot for the last 24 hours about this matter. And the most important, is buy a pure sine wave inverter, that's the first step. Second step and talking about wattage, 1000w perhaps is too much for a 150w solar panel.

I mean if I would buy at short term 5 more solar panels of that wattage, if would be OK. But as I've posted I'm starting in this world, so I gues a 500/600w would be the wisest option.